# Multiple buttons inside single php form

Tags: php

So i have this loop that shows data from my database, each of the rows will create a button that will be used later for activating/deactivating user. Now my problem is after clicking the button the output from the action.php is something like this

> action.php?course_action=1&action=activate&course_action=2&action=activate&course_action=3&action=activate&course_action=4&action=activate&course_action=5&action=activate&course_action=6&action=activate&course_action=7&action=activate&course_action=8&action=activate

it looks like after pressing the button it stores all the value from input, the expected output is something like this only

> action.php?course_action=1&action=activate

I completely forgot how to use php or just an excuse. Anyways hope you guys share some knowledge

```
<form action="db_connection/action.php" method="get">
 <?php 
   $learningcenters = json_decode(learningCenters());

   foreach ($learningcenters as $obj) {
      echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$obj->lc_id.'</td>
            <td class="txt-oflo">'.$obj->lc_name.'</td>
            <td>'.$obj->lc_emailadd.'</td>
            <td>'.$obj->lc_contactnum.'</td>
            <td class="txt-oflo">'.$obj->lc_datereg.'</td>
            <td><span class="text-success">'.$obj->lc_timereg.'</span></td>
            <td>
               <input type="hidden" name="course_action" value='.$obj->lc_id.'>
               <input type="hidden" name="action" value="activate"/>
               <input type="submit" class="act-user" value="Activate User"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>';
     }
   ?>
</form>
```

Comment: The `<submit>` will look for the parent `<form>`. You need to move the `<form>` to within the loop so that each `<submit>` will have a matching parent `<form>`. Your current code, with a single `<form>` says, send all values.

Comment: @Tigger man i didn`t think about it thanks

Comment: Only the submit button pressed is included into sent data if it has a `name` attribute. Your example does not show multiple buttons. Your actual question has nothing to do with the heading "Multiple buttons". Why would you want to prevent other form data from being sent?

Answer (score 0):

A submit button with a `name` attribute is included into the form data when it is clicked. To manage a caption differing from the `value`, use the `button` element. There should be no reason to prevent additional form data from being sent.

To be more conform to PHP as an embedded language, you should frequently close `<?php` tags rather than generating HTML outputs from strings. This also helps you to develop an MVC or similar pattern.

To get additional data per button click being sent, consider a composed string format, e.g. `:` as a delimiter.

```
<?php
 var_dump($_GET);
?>

<form>
<?php
  foreach ([3,5,6] as $id)
  {
?>
  <button name="action" type="submit" value="activate:<?php echo $id;?>">Activate</button>
<?php
  }
?>
</form>
```

You can even use array parameters. This approach also enables you to perform an action on multiple items selected by checkboxes at once.

```
<?php
  var_dump($_GET);

  if(isset($_GET['action']) && is_array($_GET['action']))
    foreach ($_GET['action'] as $id => $action)
      echo "<div>$id: $action</div>"
?>

<form>
<?php
  foreach ([3,5,6] as $id)
  {
    ?>
    <button name="action[<?php echo $id;?>]" type="submit" value="activate">Activate</button>
    <?php
  }
?>
</form>
```